# sbt: error importing resteasy-client

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am try to add keycloak client to my sbt project. And it wants a ResteasyClientBuilder, so i try to add it to libraryDependencies

and after I am type sbt update I get an error

resteasy-client was added sbt.build libraryDependencies

build.sbt file

```
name := "keycloak-akka-http"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

val akkaV = "2.4.1"
val akkaStreamV = "2.0-M2"

val akka = Seq (
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaV,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-experimental" % akkaStreamV,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json-experimental" % akkaStreamV
)

val logging = Seq (
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.12",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaV
)

val keycloak = Seq (
  "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-adapter-core" % "3.4.3.Final",
  "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-core" % "3.4.3.Final",
  "org.jboss.logging" % "jboss-logging" % "3.3.0.Final",
  "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-admin-client" % "3.4.3.Final",
  "org.jboss.resteasy" % "resteasy-client" % "3.5.0.CR2",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.1"
)

libraryDependencies ++= akka ++ logging ++ keycloak

//resolvers += "JBoss" at "https://repository.jboss.org"
//resolvers := Seq("JBoss" at "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.url("Typesafe Ivy releases", url("https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  Resolver.jcenterRepo
)
```

but during updating an error appears:

```
[info] Resolving junit#junit;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: junit#junit;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/junit/junit/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/junit/junit/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/junit/junit/working@user-System-Product-Name/junit-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/working@user-System-Product-Name/junit-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/junit/junit/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/working@user-System-Product-Name/junit-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet#jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet#jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving javax.validation#validation-api;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: javax.validation#validation-api;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/javax.validation/validation-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/javax.validation/validation-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/javax/validation/validation-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/validation-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/validation/validation-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/validation-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/javax.validation/validation-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/validation/validation-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/validation-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation#jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation#jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving javax.activation#activation;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: javax.activation#activation;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/javax.activation/activation/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/javax.activation/activation/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/javax/activation/activation/working@user-System-Product-Name/activation-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/working@user-System-Product-Name/activation-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/javax.activation/activation/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/activation/activation/working@user-System-Product-Name/activation-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: commons-io#commons-io;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/commons-io/commons-io/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/commons-io/commons-io/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/commons-io/commons-io/working@user-System-Product-Name/commons-io-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/working@user-System-Product-Name/commons-io-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/commons-io/commons-io/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/working@user-System-Product-Name/commons-io-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving net.jcip#jcip-annotations;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: net.jcip#jcip-annotations;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/net.jcip/jcip-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/net.jcip/jcip-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/jcip-annotations-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/jcip-annotations-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.jcip/jcip-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/jcip-annotations-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving javax.json.bind#javax.json.bind-api;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: javax.json.bind#javax.json.bind-api;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/javax/json/bind/javax.json.bind-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/javax.json.bind-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/json/bind/javax.json.bind-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/javax.json.bind-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/json/bind/javax.json.bind-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/javax.json.bind-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-annotations;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-annotations;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-logging-annotations-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-logging-annotations-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-logging-annotations-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-processor;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-processor;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-processor/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-processor/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-processor/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-logging-processor-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-processor/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-logging-processor-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-processor/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-processor/working@user-System-Product-Name/jboss-logging-processor-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client#microprofile-rest-client-api;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client#microprofile-rest-client-api;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client/microprofile-rest-client-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client/microprofile-rest-client-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org/eclipse/microprofile/rest/client/microprofile-rest-client-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/microprofile-rest-client-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/microprofile/rest/client/microprofile-rest-client-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/microprofile-rest-client-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client/microprofile-rest-client-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/microprofile/rest/client/microprofile-rest-client-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/microprofile-rest-client-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.microprofile.config#microprofile-config-api;working@user-System-Product-Name ...
[warn]  module not found: org.eclipse.microprofile.config#microprofile-config-api;working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.ivy2/local/org.eclipse.microprofile.config/microprofile-config-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org.eclipse.microprofile.config/microprofile-config-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/slava/.sbt/preloaded/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/microprofile-config-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/microprofile-config-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/microprofile-config-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/microprofile-config-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Ivy releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.eclipse.microprofile.config/microprofile-config-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/microprofile-config-api/working@user-System-Product-Name/microprofile-config-api-working@user-System-Product-Name.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...

warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: junit#junit;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet#jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: javax.validation#validation-api;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation#jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: javax.activation#activation;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: net.jcip#jcip-annotations;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: javax.json.bind#javax.json.bind-api;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-annotations;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-processor;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client#microprofile-rest-client-api;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.microprofile.config#microprofile-config-api;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          commons-io:commons-io:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          org.eclipse.microprofile.config:microprofile-config-api:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          javax.validation:validation-api:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          javax.json.bind:javax.json.bind-api:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          net.jcip:jcip-annotations:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          junit:junit:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          javax.activation:activation:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client:microprofile-rest-client-api:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[warn]          org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-processor:working@user-System-Product-Name
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.5.0.CR2
[warn]            +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.5.0.CR2 (/home/slava/projects/keycloak-angular-akka-http/server/build.sbt#L33-34)
[warn]            +- keycloak-akka-http:keycloak-akka-http_2.11:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: junit#junit;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet#jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.validation#validation-api;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation#jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.activation#activation;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-io#commons-io;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: net.jcip#jcip-annotations;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.json.bind#javax.json.bind-api;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-annotations;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-processor;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client#microprofile-rest-client-api;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.microprofile.config#microprofile-config-api;working@user-System-Product-Name: not found
```

how I can resolve this problem?
Actual result: an error appear
Expected result: lib must be added to sbt

Comment: Did you added or overwrite any resolvers? Maybe also check `~/.sbt/repositories`. As far as I can see it fails to download the transitive dependencies

Comment: @TobiSH, no I did not add any resolvers

Comment: @TobiSH, add this `resolvers += "JBoss" at "https://repository.jboss.org"` but the same error

Comment: Do you have any clue what "working@user-System-Product-Name" could be? Is it your username hostname?

Comment: can you post your actual build.sbt file?

Comment: @TobiSH, yes user-System-Product-Name is my system device name, but I have no user working

Comment: @marios, have added build.sbt file

Comment: Do you have any other sbt files beside the build.sbt (inside the project folder) or do you maybe have your project on github?

Comment: @TobiSH, yes I have - https://github.com/slmzig/keyCloack-client, sbt try to get dependency from url `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-admin-client_2.11/3.4.3.Final/keycloak-admin-client_2.11-3.4.3.Final.pom` but it is invalid.  But this url - `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-admin-client/3.4.3.Final/keycloak-admin-client-3.4.3.Final.pom` is valid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what exactly the problem is. But it seems like the transitive dependencies of the rest-easy-client are messed up. They don't come with any version information and that seems to be a serious problem for sbt. Maybe there is a way to tell sbt to always use the latest version that I am not aware of. But for me the following workaround works:

```
val keycloak = Seq(
"org.keycloak" % "keycloak-adapter-core" % "3.4.3.Final",
"org.keycloak" % "keycloak-core" % "3.4.3.Final",
"org.jboss.logging" % "jboss-logging" % "3.3.0.Final",
"org.jboss.logging" % "jboss-logging-annotations" % "2.1.0.Final" % "provided",
"org.jboss.logging" % "jboss-logging-processor" % "2.1.0.Final" % 
"provided",
 "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-admin-client" % "3.4.3.Final",
 "org.jboss.resteasy" % "resteasy-client" % "3.0.24.Final" excludeAll(
       ExclusionRule("junit", "junit"),
       ExclusionRule("org.jboss.logging"),
       ExclusionRule("net.jcip"),
       ExclusionRule("org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs"),
       ExclusionRule("org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet"),
       ExclusionRule("org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation"),
       ExclusionRule("javax.activation"),
       ExclusionRule("commons-io"),
       ExclusionRule("org.apache.httpcomponents")),
"org.jboss.resteasy" % "resteasy-jaxrs" % "3.0.24.Final" excludeAll(
       ExclusionRule("junit", "junit"),
       ExclusionRule("org.jboss.logging"),
       ExclusionRule("net.jcip"),
       ExclusionRule("org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs"),
       ExclusionRule("org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet"),
       ExclusionRule("org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation"),
       ExclusionRule("javax.activation"),
       ExclusionRule("commons-io"),
       ExclusionRule("org.apache.httpcomponents")),
 "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.1",
 "javax.ws.rs" % "javax.ws.rs-api" % "2.0",
 "org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation" % "jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec" % "1.0.2.Final",
 "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.6")
```

All details can be found here: https://github.com/slmzig/keyCloack-client/pull/1/files

So what I did is quite simple. Exclude all transitive dependencies which causes problems and include them explicit.

At least that works on my computer ;-)

Comment: If someone has the same issue, I had to add some other exclusion to this answer: https://gist.github.com/strokyl/01e096ab00946616070a8ed8935041aa.
By the way, thank you!